# preg_replace not matching #210

Tags: php, regex

I have a block of text with time codes in it, and I want to remove the time codes.

```
$pattern = "~(\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+\s-->\s\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+)~";
$replace = "";
$subject = "1 00:00:30,304 --> 00:00:34,165 Our focus today is to share with you 2 00:00:34,165 --> 00:00:36,715 key components of preparing and submitting 3 00:00:36,715 --> 00:00:40,715 a warranty transaction...";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $subject);
```

All of the regex testers that I've tried online say it's valid regex, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and none of the other hundreds of regex questions seem to fit my problem.

Comment: divide and conquer: first test simpler expessions that work

Comment: If there is a better place to ask Regex questions I'm ok with going there. I know there are a lot of regex questions on here, I'm just stumped on why it's not working.

Comment: What do you expect? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/aecdf337a3aa10dcd3616e3ab4e06f841f902f71

Comment: It is working for me... http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/d9s6-im5z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a better to read approach (shorter) as well:

```
$regex = "~([\d:\h,]+ --> [\d:,]+)~";
$replace = "";
$subject = "1 00:00:30,304 --> 00:00:34,165 Our focus today is to share with you 2 00:00:34,165 --> 00:00:36,715 key components of preparing and submitting 3 00:00:36,715 --> 00:00:40,715 a warranty transaction...";
echo preg_replace($regex, $replace, $subject);
```

Simply combined your patterns in a character class and used a horizontal space (`\h`) instead.
See <kbd>[a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yX4yG9/1)</kbd>.

Comment: Nice! I changed it slightly to `~([\d:\h\s+,]+ --> [\d:,]+)~` to catch the extra line break that I was missing the first time, but that definitely looks better. Thanks!

Comment: @AndyD273: `\s` includes `\h`, so you can change your first bracket to `[\d:\s,]`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is more than one space after the first number, and since I was only searching for \s it wasn't matching.
I changed it to \s+ and it worked.

The final regex string was this

~(\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+\s-->\s\d+:\d+:\d+,\d+)~
The problem was that the string in the database had new lines after the initial digit that were in the windows format (crlf).
When I copied and pasted into and the testing pages it worked since it was only a single newline, but when faced with the real data it wasn't matching any more and preg_replace wasn't catching it since I was only trying to match one white space instead of two.

After adding the + to the \s it started working.

TL;DR: Gotta remember to check my raw output in the future.